# Custom TypeConverter ConvertTo() method not called for char property

Tags: c#, .net, type-conversion

I have a class with a `char` property, that might be unprintable, which is used as part of a communications protocol.

If I rely on the default `CharConverter` class, then certain unprintable character values cannot be displayed or edited in the resulting property form (there's apparently no output for the unprintable characters). So, I've written a custom `TypeConverter` for this `char` property that outputs characters by displaying their *Unicode* codepoint as a hex value, instead of outputting the character itself.

Alas, my custom type converter's `CanConvertTo` and `ConvertTo` methods are not being called when displaying the property value; if the character is printable, then that character is displayed in the property grid, but if it's unprintable, nothing is displayed—as though the default `CharConverter` is still in use.

(Oddly, my custom type converter's `CanConvertFrom` method *is* being called, for conversion from a `string`, and returns `true`.)

Here's my class with the char property:

```cs
using System.ComponentModel;

public class SomeClass {

    // ...

    // Property for setting a communications character.
    [
        DisplayName("SomeCharacter"),
        Category("Configuration"),
        Description("Some special communications character, as a hex value."),
        TypeConverter(typeof(CustomCharConverter)),
    ]
    public char SpecialChar {
        get => // ...
        set => // ...
    }
}
```

Here's my `CustomCharConverter` class (I'm omitting the methods for converting back to a `char`, as we don't that far):

```cs
public class CustomCharConverter: TypeConverter {

    // ...

    // Overridden CanConvertTo. This is never called.
    public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType) {

        // This code never executes.
        if(destinationType == typeof(string) || destinationType == typeof(char)) {
            return true;
        }
        return base.CanConvertTo(context, destinationType);
    }

    // Overridden ConvertTo. This is never called.
    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value,
    Type destinationType) {

        // This code never executes.
        if(destinationType == typeof(string)) {
            return $"0x{((int)((char)value)):X2}"; // Convert char to hex value.
        }
        return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
    }
}
```

I haven't been able to figure out why my `ConvertTo` method has not been called to convert the `char` value to a hex value on output. Am I missing something?

Comment: Why are you using char instead of byte (or int16)?

Comment: @jdweng I'm using `char` because (a) I can make use of static `char` functions such as `IsControl`, `IsWhitespace`, without a need for conversion etc. and (b) most values can be displayed as a single text character. I could use other types, but how is that choice relevant to the answer to my question?

Comment: The method will only be called if the parameter types match.  I do not know what protocol you are using.  What you are doing may not work depending if any encoding is being used.  Encoding maps the value 0x80 to 0xFF to unicode characters (16 bit).

Comment: @jdweng The protocol is irrelevant. The type converter class is used for displaying the `char` values in a property grid, in which they're converted to strings (on output) and from strings (on input). But the type converter is not being used to perform the conversion.